# Apply Concatenate formula to entire column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

How do I apply the formula as described here..

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/76395/279173

which is this part:

`=CONCATENATE(""&LEFT(A1,10)&" ...")`

to an entire separate column along side it?

basically I want to trim a column to say max 10 characters and put the result on a new entire column side by side.

I have tried and enclosed it in ARRAYFORMULA like this one:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(""&LEFT(A1:A,10)&"..."))`

but throws a limit error and it seem not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCATENATE` will try to join *everything* inside its parentheses; so applying it to an entire column will cause Sheets to try to form one string from *all data in that column*, hence the limit error.

The ampersand alone does this in arrays.

This is how I would approach this (keeping in mind that I can't see your actual data):

`ArrayFormula(IF(A:A="",,IF(LEN(A:A)<=10,A:A,LEFT(A:A,10)&"...")))`

Comment: Thanks Erik! I guess I got confused and only needed the LEFT function. This works perfectly, problem solved.

Comment: Glad to hear you're all set.